# Adding Horizontal Line to Dash-Plotly Python Dashboard

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am creating a Dash app in Python3.  Trying to add in a horizontal line to a bar graph.  The examples in the documentation are for line graphs, which have numeric x and y axis, whereas I have a categorical X-axis.  The below code creates the graph successfully, but does not show the shape object.  How can I add a horizontal line to this graph?

```
        html.Div(
                    [    dcc.Graph(
                            id='example-graph-23',
                            figure={
                                'data': [
                                    {'x': ['Overall', 'NBA', 'WWC', 'NFL'], 'y': [3,2,2.5],
                                     'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Instagram'},
                                          ],
                                'layout': {
                                    'yaxis' : dict(
                                            range=[0, 4]
                                            ),
                                    'plot_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                                    'paper_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                                    'font': {
                                        'color': colors['text']
                                    },
                                    'shapes' : dict(type="line",
                                                    x0=0,
                                                    y0=2,
                                                    x1=5,
                                                    y1=2,
                                                    line=dict(
                                                        color="Red",
                                                        width=4,
                                                        dash="dashdot",
                                                ))
                                }
                            }
                        ) ]
        , className="four columns"
                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a vertical line by adding `x` and `y` coordinates to the `figure.data` like this:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash()

colors = {'background': 'white', 'text': 'black'}
app.layout = html.Div(
                    [    dcc.Graph(
                            id='example-graph-23',
                            figure={
                                'data': [
                                    {'x': ['Overall', 'NBA', 'WWC', 'NFL'], 'y': [3,2,2.5],
                                     'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Instagram'},
                                    {'x': ['Overall', 'Overall'], 'y': [0, 4],
                                     'type': 'line', 'name': 'v_line_1'}, 
                                    {'x': ['NBA', 'NBA'], 'y': [0, 4],
                                     'type': 'line', 'name': 'v_line_2'}, 
                                    {'x': ['WWC', 'WWC'], 'y': [0, 4],
                                     'type': 'line', 'name': 'v_line_3'},                                    
                                          ],
                                'layout': {
                                    'yaxis' : dict(
                                            range=[0, 4]
                                            ),
                                    'plot_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                                    'paper_bgcolor': colors['background'],
                                    'font': {
                                        'color': colors['text']
                                    },
                                    'shapes' : dict(type="line",
                                                    x0=0,
                                                    y0=2,
                                                    x1=5,
                                                    y1=2,
                                                    line=dict(
                                                        color="Red",
                                                        width=4,
                                                        dash="dashdot",
                                                ))
                                }
                            }
                        )], className="four columns"
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE4lF.png)

Comment: Thank you! For anyone else reading this, the above can also be modified to be a horizontal line, by switching the X and Y values in 'v_line_1'